# Create a forked process from a deamon

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I want to create a deamon in Linux that needs to kill off another process. I've created the deamon and it works fine, but my second process is created but it does not run as expected.

Is there something that I'm missing in starting the new process?

This is my code

```
void StartWSDevice()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    fflush(NULL);
    pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case -1:
          perror("fork");
          break;
    case 0: {
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "WSDevice started.");
        int res = execl("home/pi/projects/WSDevice/bin/ARM/Debug",
                        "WSDevice.out", (char *)0);
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "WSDevice return %d.", res);
        break;
    }
    default:
        fflush(NULL);
        if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1) {
            syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "Child exited with status %i\n", status);
        } else {
            perror("waitpid");
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    deamonize();
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "WSDeviceService started.");
    while (!stopService) {
        // Check if my child process is running
        int pid_file = open("/var/run/WSDevice.pid",
                            O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
        int rc = flock(pid_file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
        if (rc) {
            if (EWOULDBLOCK == errno) {
            }
        } else {
            StartWSDevice();     // Its not running, start it
        }
        sleep(30); /* wait 30 seconds */
    }
    syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "WSDeviceService terminated.");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `execl` incorrectly. The first argument to `execl()` is the process to run. The remaining arguments are the contents of the `argv` array that is passed to the process. The key here is that `argv[0]` should be the name of the process being run. So:

```
int res = execl("/home/pi/projects/WSDevice/bin/ARM/Debug/WSDevice.out",
                "/home/pi/projects/WSDevice/bin/ARM/Debug/WSDevice.out",
                NULL);
```

Note that I've also inserted `/` in front of `home`. This may be important for you. I've also used `NULL` instead of `(char *)0`, which is more of a style thing and doesn't change the functionality.

Comment: By its name, I'm also guessing `Debug` is a directory, not a binary, which would be another wrong use of `execl`.

Comment: WSDevice.out is the binary, Debug is a directory yes

Comment: @Jaques: I've updated my answer to account for your new information.

Comment: if `argv[0]` is the process being run, is `argv[1]` a parameter then? So if i don't want to pass any params, I can leave it blank?

Comment: If you don't want to pass any parameters, then do just what I wrote in my answer. The `NULL` at the end of the parameter list is always required with `execl`.

Comment: Thanks, it starts the process now, but nothing happens. It is as if the process is hanging, but I think I know what the problem is. Thanks for the help